# Dottrace profiler buttons disabled for remote asp.net application profiling

Tags: c#, asp.net, dottrace

I am using remote computer debugging for my asp.net application via dottrace .

I have set the options as :
[image]

but when I click Run a new modal is opened but with disabled buttons:
[image]

I am wondering why those buttons are disabled. How can I profile my remote asp.net web application?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer. 
dotTrace has an option to profile IIS applications, try using it instead of profiling standalone application. After configuring profiler (providing the application url), start IIS and launch your application, after that the controller buttons will be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

To profile a web application hosted in IIS, you have to launch the dottrace as admin.

Once you open the dottrace, **it will reset the IIS.** So, **there won't be any w3wp processes** running in the machine. So all the controller buttons will be in disabled mode.

Once you launch/ hit the website externally, DotTrace will find the process and so it will automatically enable the controller buttons.